# cpp operator = isn't being called (with class template)

Tags: c++, class, templates, binary-search-tree

How I defined the class:

And this is how I'm trying to call it

```
BSNode<std::string>* copy = new BSNode<std::string>("1");
copy->insert<std::string>("3");
BSNode<std::string>* copy2 = new BSNode<std::string>("2");
copy2 = copy;
```

But the function isn't being called at all, it just uses the default = (shallow copy)

The h file (That is only the c'tors and the overloading function, I don't think most of matters):

```
template <class T>
class BSNode
{
public:
template <class T>
BSNode(T data)
{
    this->_data = data;
    this->_left = nullptr;
    this->_right = nullptr;
    this->_count = 1;
}
template <class T>
BSNode<T>& operator=(const BSNode<T>& other)
{
    this->_right = new BSNode<T>(other._right->_data);
    this->_left = new BSNode<T>(other._left->_data);
    this->_count = other._count;
    this->_data = other._data;

    return *this;
}

private:
T _data;
BSNode* _left;
BSNode* _right;

int _count; 

};
```

Comment: You are working with pointers, not with the object itself

Comment: `copy2 = copy` assigns pointers to `BSNode`, not instances of `BSNode`. It simply makes `copy2` point to the same object that `copy` points to (and in the process leak the object that `copy2` used to point to previously).

Comment: Stop using the `new` keyword. If you need a pointer, use a smart pointer, and what you've shown doesn't include any reason to use any sort of pointer.

Comment: You want me to show you the entire project? this is obviously just a part of it. @aschepler

Comment: @user6394139 Don't want to see the entire project (which will include lots or irrelevant code), nor do we want to see bits of code. What is best is complete code which shows the problem you are asking about but nothing more.

Comment: That was a side recommendation which could help avoid this mistake, not really an answer or request.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
copy2 = copy;
```

copies one pointer to another pointer. It's not possible to override `operator=` for two pointers. If you want your operator to be called then do this

```
*copy2 = *copy;
```

Comment: With the new code is your operator= being called or not?

Comment: If you are expecting a deep copy then your operator= is bugged. My answer only addresses why your operator= was not called.

Comment: it is not being called either way

Comment: @user6394139 Then you've made some other mistake. Show a complete example.

Comment: I edited the post, can you help me find the mistake?

Comment: @user6394139 You should remove the inner `template <class T>` (both places) That is not necessary when you define these constructor/operator/methods inside the class. I'm not completely sure if this is the problem, but you should definitely try that first.